# angular 4 wrong routing url

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing

Hi my application implements routing, I have a list of users and when I click one of it I do this:

```
onRowSelect(event) {
this.self = event.data._links.self.href;
this.userId = this.url.getUserId(this.self, '/', 5);

this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/user-detail', this.userId]);
```

`this.userId` isn't only a id code number but a string, for example: `/users/5`
and in the user-detail.routes I define this `path: 'user-detail/:code'`

**user-detail.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.code = this.route.snapshot.params['code'];
    this.getUserDetail(this.code);
  }



  getUserDetail(code) { 
    this.http.get(this.endpointUrlService.getBaseUrl() + code, this.http.setCommonOption())

      .subscribe(response => {

        this.selected = response.json() as User;
        this.loader = 1;
      });
  }
```

The problem is that url path have the escape code '%2' for '/' like this:

> http://localhost:4200/dashboard/user-detail/%2Fusers%2F2

Is there a simple way to correct the url?

Comment: Could you give us the whole code ? Here you give us the code for `/dashboard/user-detail`, but not what follows (and that is your actual problem).

Comment: Still not enough. I guess you have to click on a user to navigate, right ? Then I will need the html of the actual link. My guess is that you have misused the `[routerLink]` attribute

Comment: Is not really a `[routerLink]` is a primeNg table with selection mode

Comment: Ok so the problem is in your `this.self = event.data._links.self.href;`. Could you log it and post the result ?

Comment: this is correct, the application gives me the correct user in my http.get, all works, only the url is wrong formed

Comment: Yes, because it has a space. That can only be added during either `this.self = event.data._links.self.href;`, or `this.userId = this.url.getUserId(this.self, '/', 5);` you can try to do `this.userId = this.userId.replace(' ', '');` to see if it works.

Comment: It has no space ` this.userId = /users/3`

Comment: Ok so do `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/user-detail/users', this.userId]);` where userId is only equal to 5 (I mean, not 5, but only a number, you get me)

Comment: That's what I've already suggested him ;].

Comment: Yes it works with number, but I need a string like: /users/4

Answer (score 0):

It is a good approach to navigate to route like

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard', 'user-detail', 'users', userId]);
```

That's why `navigate` takes array as a param, not a string.
There's another method

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/'dashboard/user-detail${userId}`)
```

Which you can use.

Edited

Comment: Thanks but my userId needs to be a path like this `/users/5`

Comment: OK, did you try with `navigationByUrl`. Also if your string in `userId` is still encoded you can try to decode it with `decodeURIComponent(userId)`

Comment: with navigationByUrl the url is good but the path: 'user-detail/:code' in user-detail.routes is still right? with navigationByUrl I can't pass userId to user.detail component